# Can an old car engine be used outside of a car?

Tags: engine

After selling my car for salvage recently I began to wonder if I could repurpose my next car's engine for anything. Can old car engines be made into generators or other useful machines?

Answer (score 2):

Basically the sky is the limit. If you can dream of something which it can connect to, you could utilize it. There are limits, of course. I mean, you couldn't pull out a 400lb engine and expect to put it in an RC car. If you can devise a way to mount it and attach it to an object which needs power, you can make it happen.

Things which I've seen engines used for outside of cars:

- Airplanes (or other flying *things*)
- [Air boats](https://www.google.com/search?hl=en&authuser=0&site=imghp&tbm=isch&source=hp&biw=1207&bih=852&q=v8+powered+airboats)
- Generators (though, this use is abusive to a car engine due to the constant RPMs needed to run the gennie)
- Larger water pumps
- Tractor engines (replacements when the original has bit the dust - takes some work, but it can be done)
- Other cars
- [Chain Saws](https://www.google.com/search?hl=en&authuser=0&site=imghp&tbm=isch&source=hp&biw=1207&bih=852&q=v8+powered+chainsaw)
- [Snow Blowers](https://www.google.com/search?hl=en&authuser=0&site=imghp&tbm=isch&source=hp&biw=1207&bih=852&q=v8+powered+snowblower)
- [Motor Cycles](https://www.google.com/search?hl=en&authuser=0&site=imghp&tbm=isch&source=hp&biw=1207&bih=852&q=v8+powered+motorcycle)

Answer (score 2):

To add to Paul's answer - conventional boats are a very common application for old car engines, a good example of this being the 'long-tail' boats found in South-East Asia, which often use them: see [This wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long-tail_boat) for example...